# jQuery onclick event on two elements

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with changing the onclick event on two elements on top of eachother.

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/qkarq2s4/

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("div.list").click(function() {

    $("div.list").not(this).slideUp();
    $("div.showall").hide().delay(200).fadeIn(200);
    $("div.list" ).off( "click");

    $("div.showall").click(function() {
        $("div.list").show(200);
        $("div.showall").hide();
    });

  });
});
```

1) Onclick shows the selected div only + the [show all] link
2) Click on [show all] shows all divs

This works, but only once (you have to reload the page, or click Run in jsFiddle)
http://jsfiddle.net/qkarq2s4/

Comment: Well if you remove the click handler by using `.off`, then what else would you expect to happen …?

Comment: I would expect a comment from someone named CBroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qkarq2s4/1/

I have fixed. The problem with your code that is not working second time is that you unset the click for the **div.list** 
Removing that will do the trick, and also we will need to add **stopPropagation** for the **div.showall** to not fire click event to the parent divs.

Here is working code:

```
$("div.list").click(function() {

    $("div.list").not(this).slideUp();
    $("div.showall").hide().delay(200).fadeIn(200);

    $("div.showall").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("div.list").show(200);
        $("div.showall").hide();
    });

});
```